# How to check whether the Location API using Google Play Services is currently running or not?

Tags: android, google-location-services

Is there any way to know whether the location api service is running or not.
if not running i need to start again the location service.

The purpose is that: the location service is stopped when device is rebooted.I need to start it again when the service stopped.

Comment: How did you integrate location api ? I mean did you use any service ? if possible share your code

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, pendingIntent);

Comment: are you doing this inside a service and calling it periodically ?

Comment: No I'm using it inside my main activity and the updated location will be passed to intent service and the intent service will update the current  location to my shared preference . So that i can use it when ever i wanted.

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer of this question.